# Verifying successful row creation in when using prepared_insert in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

How can I verify successful row creation (and modification) when using prepared_insert in PDO?

Here is my code:

```
    try {
    $options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    function escape_mysql_identifier($field){
        return "`".str_replace("`", "``", $field)."`";
    }

    function prepared_insert($pdo, $table, $data) {
        $keys = array_keys($data);
        $keys = array_map('escape_mysql_identifier', $keys);
        $fields = implode(",", $keys);
        $table = escape_mysql_identifier($table);
        $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($keys) - 1) . '?';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($placeholders)";
        $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array_values($data));
    }

    $data = array_filter($data);

    //var_dump ($data);

    prepared_insert($conn, 'products', $data);

    $id = $conn->lastInsertId();

    if ($id > 0) {
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'success','message'≥'Row successfully added'));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'danger','message'≥'Row not successfully added'));
    }

}catch(PDOException $e){
    
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'danger','message'=>$e->getMessage()));
}
    $conn = null;
```

As you can see, right now I am doing it by using `lastInsertId()` but I do not think that's the correct way to do it.

Additionally, if the row was not created, how can I capture the error behind it and report it?

Comment: What error are you expecting? Why are you exposing the PDO error message to the users? What do they need it for?

Answer (score -1):

you not need create this condition :

```
if ($id > 0) {
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'success','message'≥'Row successfully added'));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'danger','message'≥'Row not successfully added'));
}
```

because you using try and catch.. you can make sure it with database transaction.. try to commit and catch to rollback..

Comment: Yeah that's not working for me. If there's a MySQL error it doesn't give a response. Is something wrong with my code?